# Go GC stopping my goroutine?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I have been trying to get into Go from the more traditional languages such as Java and C and so far I've been enjoying the well-thought out design choices that Go offers. When I started my first "real" project though, I ran into a problem that almost nobody seems to have.

My project is a simple networking implementation that sends and receives packets. The general structure is something like this (of course simplified):

A client manages the `net.Conn` with the server. This `Client`creates a `PacketReader`and a `PacketWriter`. These both run infinite loops in a different goroutine. The `PacketReader` takes an interface with a single `OnPacketReceived` function that is implemented by the client.

The `PacketReader` code looks something like this:

```
go func() {
    for {
        bytes, err := reader.ReadBytes(10) // Blocks the current routine until bytes are available.
        if err != nil {
            panic(err) // Handle error
        }
        reader.handler.OnPacketReceived(reader.parseBytes(bytes))
    }
}()
```

The `PacketWriter` code looks something like this:

```
go func() {

    for {
        if len(reader.packetQueue) > 0 {
            // Write packet
        }
    }
}()
```

In order to make `Client` blocking, the client makes a channel that gets filled by `OnPacketReceived`, something like this:

```
type Client struct {
    callbacks map[int]chan interface{}
    // More fields
}

func (c *Client) OnPacketReceived(packet *Packet) {
    c.callbacks[packet.Id] <- packet.Data
}

func (c *Client) SendDataBlocking(id int, data interface{}) interface{} {
    c.PacketWriter.QueuePacket(data)
    return <-c.callbacks[id]
}
```

Now here is my problem: the `reader.parseBytes` function does some intensive decoding operation that creates quite a lot of objects (to the point that the GC decides to run). *The GC however, pauses the reader goroutine that is currently decoding the bytes, and then hangs*. A problem that seems similar to mine is described [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12553). I have confirmed that it is actually the GC causing it, because running it with `GOGC=off` runs successfully.

At this point, my 3 routines look like this:
- `Client (main routine)`: Waiting for channel
- `Writer`: Still running, waiting for new data in queue
- `Reader`: Set as runnable, but not actually running

Somehow, the GC is either not able to stop all routines in order to run, or it does not resume said goroutines after it stopped them.

So my question is this: **Is there any way to fix this?** I am new to Go so I don't really know if my design choices are even remotely conventional, and I'm all up with changing the structure of my program. Do I need to change the way I handle packet reading callbacks, do I need to try and make the packet decoder less intensive? Thanks!

**Edit**: I am running Go 1.5.1, I'll try to get a working example later today.

Comment: I'd recommend adding your Go version and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question so that more people could try to reproduce and tell you what's wrong.

Comment: unrelated sidenote: In your`PacketWriter` you should use a channel (and `range` over it) rather than the busy `for` loop

Comment: Oh, my sidenote may not be that unrelated: try adding a `runtime.Gosched()` inside of that tight `for` loop in the writer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [mrd0ll4r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292835/mrd0ll4r)s comment, changed the writer to use channels instead of a slice (I don't even know why I did that in the first place). That seemed to give the GC enough "mobility" to allow the threads to stop. Adding in the `runtime.Gosched()` and still using slices also worked though, but the channels seemed more "go-esque".